# my phone is kinda slow

Tags: nokia-lumia-830

I turned on narrator though it was not intentional.and after that my phone became locked.after 2 hours finally I could hard-reset it.but from that time on, my phone is not the same as it was before.the touch has become awful.does not download apps easily and some other stuff.for the 2 first weeks I was quit satisfied with my purchase but now, not even a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, are you sure you hard-reset it? A *typical reset* is the following:

```
Settings > About > Reset your phone
```

A *hard reset* involves the [Windows Recovery Tool](http://download-fds.webapps.microsoft.com/supportFiles/phones/files/recovery/WindowsPhoneRecoveryToolInstaller.exe). In order to do this, follow the next steps:

1. Make a backup of everything you need (photos etc) before starting.
2. Download the [Windows Recovery Tool](http://download-fds.webapps.microsoft.com/supportFiles/phones/files/recovery/WindowsPhoneRecoveryToolInstaller.exe) to your computer.
3. Connect your Windows Phone to the PC with the USB Cable. If your
   phone is not automatically detected, disconnect it from your
   computer and press ‘My phone was not detected’ at the bottom and
   follow the instructions on the screen.
4. After the phone is detected, tap the phone model on the screen to
   continue.
5. The next screen shows the available software versions. Tap the
   reinstall button at the bottom
6. There’s a disclaimer that suggests backing up your phone. Tap
   continue at the bottom.
7. The recovery tool downloads and installs the firmware. This may take
   a while depending on your network connection. The installation files
   are about 1.7 GB. Make sure not to disconnect the cable.
8. If all goes well, you get a message that says, “Operation
   successfully completed.”

So, if you haven't done an actual **hard** reset, do it. If you *have* done it, do it again, maybe something went wrong with the procedure. If the problem persists I imagine that it's a hardware issue, so in this case you should contact customer support.